# Is there a way to search for all content except my own?

Tags: support, users, search

I tried to get all tcl posts that are not from my own authorship

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=tcl%20-user%3ame

using

```
tcl -user:me
```

but it interpreted it as posts not containing the string "user:me".

---

I also tried

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=tcl+user%3A-me

using

```
tcl user:-me
```

but it interpreted it as posts containing the string "user:-me"

---

Is there a way to get what was not posted by me? If there is not, I suggest to implement it using the syntax I tried.

Comment: Isn't this more suitable for MetaSE?

Comment: No. It is perfectly acceptable to post questions like this on a per-site Meta, @icri

Answer (score 5):

Use the Data Explorer:

http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/726867